# Remove need for same-named package directory when using setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm just starting to dabble in using `setuptools` to make it easier to distribute a collection of classes that I use at work.

I currently have a directory structure of (actual names changed for simplicity):

- my_parsers

  - __init__.py
  - file1.py
  - file2.py
  - setup.py

With this directory structures, when installing this package into another environment, I import things using `from file1 import MyClass`.

What I'd like to be able to do is import things using `from my_parsers.file1 import MyClass`. To accomplish this, I know that I can change my directory structure to have a subdirectory of `my_parsers` with `__init__.py`, `file1.py`, and `file2.py` in it.

But it seems silly to me that I need to have a subdirectory named the same thing as my root directory for such a simple project.

**Is there a way to configure setuptools in my `setup.py` to package this such that it can be imported using `from my_parsers.file1 import MyClass` without the need for this subdirectory?**

FWIW, here's my current `setup.py` (with non-relavent details removed, such as description, version, etc.):

```
from setuptools import setup


setup(
    name='my_parsers',

    package_dir={'my_parsers': ''},
    packages=['my_parsers'],
)
```

Comment: I asked the same question long time ago. After 3 years of research, I think the answer is still no :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587667/folderless-namespaced-packages-with-setuptools

Comment: Thanks for the info. That likely explains why I can't find anything about it anywhere.